# How to get an object infront of an image in Java Processing 3.x?

Tags: java, image-processing, processing

Hi I've had a problem where I'm unable to put the ellipse onto the map. Instead what happens is that the ellipse loads for a second and then the map continues to load after this. I've added the code below to see if anyone can help?

```
PImage map; 
float zoom = 1;
float posX = 0;
float posY = 0;

void setup() {
  size (800, 800, P3D);
  loadData();
  map = loadImage("uk-admin.jpg");
 
}

void draw () {
 background (0);
 translate(posX,posY);
 scale(zoom);
 image(map, 0,0, width, height);
 camera(width/2, height/2, (height/2) / tan(PI*30.0 / 180.0),width/2.0, height/2.0 , 0, 0, 1, 0);
}

Table table;

void loadData() {
  table = loadTable("data.csv", "header");

  for (int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++) {
    TableRow row = table.getRow(i);

    String city = row.getString("City");
    int year1991 = row.getInt("1991");
    int year2001 = row.getInt("2001");
    int year2011 = row.getInt("2011");
    float lat = row.getFloat("latitude");
    float lon =  row.getFloat("longitude");
    
     lat = map(lat, 90.0, -90.0, 0, height);
     lon = map(lon, -180.0, 180.0, 0, width);
     fill(255);                      
     stroke(10);
     ellipse(lon, lat, 30, 30);
   
   
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `loadData()` in the `draw()` loop. What's happening now is that you're drawing the ellipse for the first frame, then you're drawing the image on top of it every frame after that.

In Processing, the `setup()` block is run once, then the current state of the canvas is displayed, then the `draw()` block is run, then the  canvas displayed, then `draw()`, then display, and so on. So when you draw an ellipse (or a bunch of ellipses) in `setup()`, then draw something over that ellipse in `draw()`, it only shows the ellipse for the first frame.

Comment: @MarcBrolly I'm glad it helped! Could you mark my answer as accepted so that others know that it is solved? Thanks!